# Using hoogle in a haskell development environment on nix

Tags: haskell, nixos, hoogle

I'm trying to use hoogle in a Haskell development environment exactly
like the one described by [O'Charles' wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20160407215009/http://wiki.ocharles.org.uk/Nix):

I have modified `shell.nix` like below in order to use `hoogleLocal`, but it doesn't seem to install the hoogle binary for me.

```
let
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};

  # I'm attempting to use hoogle here, but it is not working.
  haskellPackages =
    let callPackage = pkgs.lib.callPackageWith haskellPackages;
    in pkgs.recurseIntoAttrs (pkgs.haskellPackages.override {
      extension = self: super: {
        thiscurrentpackage = self.callPackage ./. {};
        hoogleLocal = pkgs.haskellPackages.hoogleLocal.override {
          packages = self.thiscurrentpackage;
        };
      };
    });
in pkgs.myEnvFun {
  name = haskellPackages.thiscurrentpackage.name;
  buildInputs = [
    (haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (hs: ([
      hs.cabalInstall
      hs.ghcMod
      hs.yesodBin
      # This doesn't appear to install the hoogle binary?
      hs.hoogleLocal
    ] ++ hs.thiscurrentpackage.propagatedNativeBuildInputs)))
  ];
}
```

In the resulting shell, the `hoogle` binary is not available.

If I include `hs.hoogle` to the `buildInputs`, the `hoogle` binary is installed but it can't find the databases.  Below is what happens when I try to use it.

```sh
$ nix-shell
......
$ hoogle Monad
Could not find some databases: default
Searching in:
  .
    /nix/store/91y9q2y5a2ws8xgcsx1gkhfagc0f2qz6-haskell-hoogle-ghc7.8.3-4.2.36-shared/share/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.8.3/hoogle-4.2.36/databases

    There are no available databases, generate them with: hoogle data
$ hoogle data
    hoogle: /nix/store/91y9q2y5a2ws8xgcsx1gkhfagc0f2qz6-haskell-hoogle-ghc7.8.3-4.2.36-shared/share/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.8.3/hoogle-4.2.36/databases:
changeWorkingDirectory: does not exist (No such file or directory)
$
```

How do I get this working correctly for a setup like described by O'Charles?

**Edit**: The original shell.nix is the same one from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27284762/3040129).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's what my Nix Haskell dev environment looks like

in `~/.nixpkgs/config.nix`:

### The environment helper function

First off, define a haskellEnvFun function for building Haskell environments:

```
packageOverrides = super: rec {

haskellEnvFun = { withHoogle ? false, compiler ? null, name }:
  let hp = if compiler != null
             then super.haskell.packages.${compiler}
             else haskellPackages;

      ghcWith = if withHoogle
                  then hp.ghcWithHoogle
                  else hp.ghcWithPackages;

  in super.buildEnv {
    name = name;
    paths = [(ghcWith myHaskellPackages)];
  };
```

### Defining some environments

Call this function to define two environments: one for running the Hoogle builder on changes, and one without:

```
haskellEnvHoogle = haskellEnvFun {
  name = "haskellEnvHoogle";
  withHoogle = true;
};

haskellEnv = haskellEnvFun {
  name = "haskellEnv";
  withHoogle = false;
};
```

### Packages

Define all the packages you want to use in your local Haskell dev environment:

```
myHaskellPackages = hp: with hp; [
  Boolean
  HTTP
  HUnit
  MissingH
  QuickCheck
  SafeSemaphore
  Spock
  aeson
  async
  attoparsec
  bifunctors
  blaze-builder
  blaze-builder-conduit
  blaze-builder-enumerator
  blaze-html
  blaze-markup
  blaze-textual
  cased
  cassava
  cereal
  comonad
  comonad-transformers
  directory_1_2_4_0
  dlist
  dlist-instances
  doctest
  exceptions
  fingertree
  foldl
  free
  hamlet
  hashable
  hspec
  hspec-expectations
  html
  http-client
  http-date
  http-types
  io-memoize
  keys
  language-c
  language-javascript
  language-bash
  lens
  lens-action
  lens-aeson
  lens-datetime
  lens-family
  lens-family-core
  lifted-async
  lifted-base
  linear
  list-extras
  list-t
  logict
  mime-mail
  mime-types
  mmorph
  monad-control
  monad-coroutine
  monad-loops
  monad-par
  monad-par-extras
  monad-stm
  monadloc
  mongoDB
  monoid-extras
  network
  newtype
  numbers
  optparse-applicative
  parsec
  parsers
  pcg-random
  persistent
  persistent-mongoDB
  persistent-template
  pipes
  pipes-async
  pipes-attoparsec
  pipes-binary
  pipes-bytestring
  pipes-concurrency
  pipes-csv
  pipes-extras
  pipes-group
  pipes-http
  pipes-mongodb
  pipes-network
  pipes-parse
  pipes-safe
  pipes-shell
  pipes-text
  posix-paths
  postgresql-simple
  pretty-show
  profunctors
  random
  reducers
  reflection
  regex-applicative
  regex-base
  regex-compat
  regex-posix
  regular
  relational-record
  resourcet
  retry
  rex
  safe
  sbv
  scotty
  semigroupoids
  semigroups
  shake
  shakespeare
  shelly
  simple-reflect
  speculation
  split
  spoon
  stm
  stm-chans
  stm-stats
  streaming
  streaming-bytestring
  streaming-wai
  strict
  stringsearch
  strptime
  syb
  system-fileio
  system-filepath
  tagged
  taggy
  taggy-lens
  tar
  tardis
  tasty
  tasty-hspec
  tasty-hunit
  tasty-quickcheck
  tasty-smallcheck
  temporary
  test-framework
  test-framework-hunit
  text
  text-format
  time
  tinytemplate
  transformers
  transformers-base
  turtle
  uniplate
  unix-compat
  unordered-containers
  uuid
  vector
  void
  wai
  wai-conduit
  warp
  wreq
  xhtml
  yaml
  zippers
  zlib
];
```

### Shell helpers

In your `~/.profile` define a couple bash functions to load those environments for convenience:

```
env-type () {
  envtype="$1"
  shift
  nix-shell -Q -p $envtype "$@"
}

haskell-env () {
  env-type "haskellEnv" "$@"
}

haskell-env-hoogle () {
  env-type "haskellEnvHoogle" "$@"
}
```

### Hoogle

Call `haskell-env-hoogle` in your shell. This will build all of your packages + docs and load you into an environment with `hoogle` in scope. At this point I usually type:

```
hoogle server --local -p 8080 &> /tmp/hoogle.log & disown
```

to launch a hoogle server the the background. Eventually I want to have a systemd service for this so that I can just nixos-rebuild to regen docs and launch the server automatically.

### Emacs

For emacs I've set the `haskell-hoogle-url` to `http://localhost:8080/?hoogle=%s`, so that I can get local hoogle docs for keywords under my cursor. I use spacemacs so I just type `, h h` for this functionality.

You can see my full nixpkgs config here: https://github.com/jb55/nix-files/blob/659798f2ca81fb7ad0cb5a29de576024ee16eef8/nixpkgs/config.nix#L20

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 14):

`haskellPackages.hoogleLocal` appears to be out of date; it doesn't exist anymore.

William Casarin's answer appears to be assuming you will have a single "haskell development environment" you use, rather than using nix-shell to have different dev environments for different projects.

What I've just figured out how to do instead is to write my shell.nix to override `ghc.withPackages` and `ghcWithPackages` to be `ghc.withHoogle`, so that when nix-shell creates an environment with a GHC that knows about all the necessary packages it also creates a hoogle database that knows about the same packages.

Here's my shell.nix<sup>1</sup>:

```
{ nixpkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}, compiler ? "default", withHoogle ? true }:

let

  inherit (nixpkgs) pkgs;

  f = import ./default.nix;

  packageSet = (
    if compiler == "default"
      then  pkgs.haskellPackages
      else  pkgs.haskell.packages.${compiler}
  );

  haskellPackages = (
    if withHoogle
      then  packageSet.override {
              overrides = (self: super:
                {
                  ghc = super.ghc // { withPackages = super.ghc.withHoogle; };
                  ghcWithPackages = self.ghc.withPackages;
                }
              );
            }
      else  packageSet
  );

  drv = haskellPackages.callPackage f {};

in

  if pkgs.lib.inNixShell then drv.env else drv
```

I'm newish to nix, but I believe this should be pretty much "project independent"; I can use `cabal2nix . > default.nix` to generate a nix package from my cabal file when I change it, without having to touch shell.nix.

I haven't actually used this in real development yet, only a dummy project I was using to try to figure out how to get hoogle working in nix-shell.

---

<sup>1</sup>The skeleton of this was what `cabal2nix --shell` spits out, with the project-specific guts removed and replaced with `f = import ./default.nix` instead of embedding the nixified cabal package again.

Comment: Yup! I used to do it this way. When writing lots of Haskell code I find it easier to just have everything in one shell for rapid development. But this works great if you only have one project you're working on.

Answer (score 2):

Using @Ben's answer as reference, here is a diff on the required changes I needed to make to a `cabal2nix --shell` file:

````
diff --git a/shell.nix b/shell.nix
index 540ade3..e207d6e 100644
--- a/shell.nix
+++ b/shell.nix
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-{ nixpkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}, compiler ? "default", doBenchmark ? false }:
+{ nixpkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}, compiler ? "default", doBenchmark ? false , withHoogle ? true}:

 let

@@ -21,10 +21,23 @@ let
         license = stdenv.lib.licenses.bsd3;
       };

-  haskellPackages = if compiler == "default"
+  haskellPackages' = if compiler == "default"
                        then pkgs.haskellPackages
                        else pkgs.haskell.packages.${compiler};

+  haskellPackages = (
+    if withHoogle
+    then  haskellPackages'.override {
+      overrides = (self: super:
+        {
+          ghc = super.ghc // { withPackages = super.ghc.withHoogle; };
+          ghcWithPackages = self.ghc.withPackages;
+        }
+      );
+    }
+    else haskellPackages'
+  );
+
   variant = if doBenchmark then pkgs.haskell.lib.doBenchmark else pkgs.lib.id;

   drv = variant (haskellPackages.callPackage f {});```
````